# HTTP validation utilities?

Tags: http

Does anyone know of a utility that can check whether a HTTP request/response is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark (used to be known as Ethereal).

http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 4):

Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Does Fiddler really check whether the data conforms to the standard?

Comment: I can't find any features for HTTP validation/error checking either.

Comment: First of all, in the question it was not exactly defined which kind of validation needed. Fiddler is very powerful. It has opened extension interface. Extensions like Watcher with open source found on codeplex, for example, can detect a lot of security issues. Fiddler can be used in different scenarios (Fiddler running on remote computer, for example, can be used as proxy to trace/ verify HTTP traffic). I don’t want to write a long text here, but I recommend watching video http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/CL25, where Fiddler developer Eric Lawrence explains Fiddler’s features.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [HTTP Analyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/)?

ps. It's a non-free tool, but I'm in no way affiliated.